# Non-empty subsets from HackerEarth exercises

Tags: java, algorithm, bufferedreader, minmax

Actually, I am doing an [exercise from HackerEarth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/minor-4-41918cb8/).

The exercise is pretty simple: I have to use a min-max algorithm but I have some struggles when I use the `readLine` method from the variable `BufferReader`.

I cannot figure out why but my `min` variable for an iteration keep the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

##### Code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        //BufferedReader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
        
        while (T-- >= 0) {
            String[] line = br.readLine().trim().split("\\s");
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length - 1; i++) {
                min = Math.min(min, Integer.parseInt(line[i]));
            }

            System.out.println(min);
        }

        
    }
}
```

##### Output

```
1
2147483647
2
```

Comment: You've shown the output, but not the input.

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger. I assume the second line of the input is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made many corrections to your code.

1. You are not reading every N of every test case, you only read it once. You have to put it inside the while loop.
2. Method trim is unnecessary because inputs from the problems are always in the right manner.
3. Use > not >= when comparing using array lengths or the number of test cases, because it will iterate once more even if the index is already beyond the array's capacity or 0.

```
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    //BufferedReader
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        
    while (T-- > 0) {
        br.readLine(); // to read N
        String[] line = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
            min = Math.min(min, Integer.parseInt(line[i]));
        }

        System.out.println(min);
    }
}
```